# mdframed causes "too many floats" error

Tags: errors, mdframed

I defined a new environemnt `examples` for a book I am writing. I would like examples to be with a framed grey box, and use the following construct

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% EXAMPLES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newlistof[chapter]{examples}{exp}{\listexamples}
\newcommand{\bex}[1]{%
\begin{mdframed}[linewidth=2, leftmargin=0, rightmargin=0, backgroundcolor=gray, linecolor=black, splittopskip=\topskip, skipbelow=\baselineskip, skipabove=\baselineskip]
\refstepcounter{examples}
\par\noindent\sqrblt\underline{\textbf{Example \theexamples. #1}}
\addcontentsline{exp}{examples}
{\protect\numberline{\theexamples}#1}\par}
\cftsetindents{examples}{0em}{2em} % for example numbers which are greater than 9
% Solution
\newcommand{\sol}{\begin{center}\underline{{\bf Solution:}}\end{center}}
% End of Example
\newcommand{\eex}{
\noindent \hbox{~~}\hfill \hbox{~~} \sqrblt
\end{mdframed}
}
```

If I activate the `mdframed`, I get "not in outer par mode". If I comment the `mdframed` part, all is well

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Please post a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) of your code illustrating the problem.

Comment: If I try your commands, I get what seems to be expected. What's the real error you get? The title says "too many floats", the questions refers to "not in outer par mode"

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution which works.

Your feedback is welcome.

```
\setcounter{errorcontextlines}{999}
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
\usepackage{tocloft}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% EXAMPLES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newlistof[chapter]{examples}{exp}{\listexamples}
\cftsetindents{examples}{0em}{2em}
\newcommand*\listexamples{List of Examples}

\newcommand{\sqrblt}{\rule{0.1in}{0.1in}\hspace{.05in}}

\mdfdefinestyle{example}{%
   linewidth=2,
   leftmargin=0,
   rightmargin=0,
   backgroundcolor=gray,
   linecolor=black,
   splittopskip=\topskip,
   skipbelow=\baselineskip,
   skipabove=\baselineskip,
   frametitlefont=\bfseries,}

\newenvironment{examplesenv}[1]%
   {\refstepcounter{examples}%
    \addcontentsline{exp}{examples}{\protect\numberline{\theexamples}#1}
    \begin{mdframed}[style=example,frametitle={\sqrblt Example \theexamples.~#1}]
   }{\mbox{}\hspace{0.2in}\mbox{}\hfill\llap{\sqrblt}\end{mdframed}}

\let\bex\examplesenv
\let\eex\endexamplesenv

\usepackage{showframe,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\listofexamples
\chapter{foo}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{examplesenv}{Example one}
\lipsum[1]
\end{examplesenv}
\clearpage
\bex{Example two}
\lipsum[1]
\eex
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

In a comment [zampano](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/8292/zampano) wrote he insert a floating environment. This can't work. The explanation if given in the [UK List of TeX Frequently Asked Questions](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html-beta?label=figurehere)

> This is of course a contradiction: figure and table are designed to
>   float, and will always have the potential to appear away from where
>   you asked for them. Therefore you have to find a means of getting the
>   caption and other effects without allowing the figure or table to
>   float.

To use `captions` in this contents I prefer the method `captionof` (provided by the `KOMA-script` or by the packages `caption` or `capt-of`)

```
\begin{center}
 \includegraphics{picture}
  \captionof{figure}{foo}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: Sure, it works, but the moment you insert inside the example a figure (\begin{figure} \includegraphics etc...) it fails with not in outer mode immediately

Comment: @zampano: This is an information which you forgot to present. You can't insert `float`-objects.  If you want to use the `caption` you can use the `center`-environment in combination with captionof.